# double integral of density function for mass: where went wrong

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider upper half of ellipse:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\leq 1$$
with density
$$\rho(x,y)=2x^2y$$
with two ways of integration:
$$\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{0}^{b\cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}2x^2ydydx=\int_{-a}^{a}2b^2(x^2-x^4/a^2)=2b^2(2/3a^2-2a^5/5a^2)=\frac{8}{15}a^3b^2$$
$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^{1}2a^2u^2cos^2(v)b\cdot u\cdot sin(v)(abu)dudv=\frac{4}{15}a^3b^2$$

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: $$\int y\,dy=\frac12y^2$$ You forgot the factor $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct  , the first one on the other hand has the constant value $4/15$ just repeat the calculation...  After the integration of $dy$ you must get $(x*b)^2 -x^4 *(b/a)^2$  and then since it is an even function you can now integrate from $0$ to $a$ and multiply by $2$.

Comment: Hi, I have edited it and added more step, would you please have a look once again?

Comment: As mentioned in another comment , you forgot the 1/2 while integrating y